# How to automatically update AMI in Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Launch Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How can I update the AMI in an Auto Scaling configuration after updating code in an EC2 instance? I don't need to use AWS CodeDeploy.

I have simple script, but it is still requires me to manually type the Image ID:

1) Create AMI

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id i-0b09axxx --name "My server" --no-reboot
```

2) Create new Auto Scaling Launch Configuration

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name "new-launch-configuration-name" --image-id "new-AMI-id"
```

3) Update Auto Scaling Launch Configuration with new AMI

```
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name "current-autoscaling-group-name" --launch-configuration-name "new-launch-configuration-name"
```

4) Delete old Auto Scaling Launch Configuration

```
aws autoscaling delete-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name "old-launch-configuration-name"
```

Comment: Capture the output of the first command, parse out the new image ID into a variable, then use that variable in the second command.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this (assuming you're using Linux):

```
#Define parameters
INSTANCE=i-abcd1234
ASG_NAME="current-autoscaling-group-name"
OLD_LC="old-launch-configuration-name"
NEW_LC="new-launch-configuration-name"

# Create AMI
IMAGE=`aws ec2 create-image --instance-id $INSTANCE --name NEW-IMAGE --output text`

# Create Launch Configuration
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name $NEW_LC --image-id $IMAGE --instance-type t2.micro

# Update Auto Scaling Group to use new Launch Configuration
aws autoscaling update-auto-scaling-group --auto-scaling-group-name $ASG_NAME --launch-configuration-name $NEW_LC

# Delete old Auto Scaling Launch Configuration
aws autoscaling delete-launch-configuration --launch-configuration-name $OLD_LC
```